# Running my own Swift app on real device shows only LaunchScreen

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I can run my Swift app(Xcode) on real device, but it shows only LaunchScreen. I waited for more than 20 minutes, but nothing else shows. Anyone know, why there is this problem?

Comment: Are there any errors? Does it work in a simulator? What if you run on another device? Are you talking about iOS or macOS App?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try. You haven't given a lot of detail but from my understanding you have tried pairing it with a physical device and can only see the initial screen when you run the app.

I would try

1. Restarting Xcode
2. Making sure the app works on simulator
3. Unplugging and Replugging the cable into your phone
4. Restarting your phone

Comment: The answer was I didn't check the start view controller's "inherit module from target" box